# How to execute a powershell file in batch repeatadly

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a question. With my batch program I want to call a powershell program to replace words. I tried it with batch, but in my files are very often exclamation marks and yeah...batch don`t like these. So I take my batch strings and put them into powershell. This works perfectly fine. But I want to repeat this with other words and there is my problem.

```
set /a loop=0

:inta
set /a loop=%loop%+1

call:DoReplace "%Torsten%" "%Torsten:~0,-1%%loop%"    cache\%KlausDieter:~0,-5%%loop%%Rainer%    cache1\%KlausDieter:~0,-5%%loop%%Rainer%
exit /b

:DoReplace
echo ^(Get-Content "%3"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 } ^| Set-Content %4>Rep.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File Rep.ps1
if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
GOTO :wer

:wer
set installel=%errorlevel%
if %loop%==%count% goto fall
if %installel%==0 goto inta

:fall




set /a loop=0

:intal
set /a loop=%loop%+1

call:DoReplaceL "%Horst%" "%Horst:~0,-1%%loop%"    cache0\%Bruno:~0,-5%%loop%%Rainer%    cache1\%Bruno:~0,-5%%loop%%Rainer%
exit /b

:DoReplaceL
echo ^(Get-Content "%3"^) ^| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace %1, %2 } ^| Set-Content %4>Rep.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File Rep.ps1
if exist Rep.ps1 del Rep.ps1
GOTO :werl

:werl
set installel=%errorlevel%
if %loop%==%count% goto falll
if %installel%==0 goto intal

:falll
```

When I call it a second time there come a error with: Argument "Rep.ps1" isn`t available. Isn`t it possible to do such things?

I am from Germany so sorry for the bad english.

Thank you for your help

Markus

My batch-code for search and replace was this. Maybe you will find a mistake to get rid of problems with exclamation marks:

```
set /a loop=0


:inta
set /a loop=%loop%+1

SET "quell_datei=cache\%KlausDieter:~0,-5%%loop%.cin"
SET "ziel_datei=cache1\%KlausDieter:~0,-5%%loop%.cin"
SET "suchen_nach=%Torsten%1"
SET "ersetzen_durch=%Torsten%%loop%"


IF NOT DEFINED suchen_nach (ECHO. Fehler: Die Variable suchen_nach nicht definiert^^!&GOTO :eof)

del "%ziel_datei%" >nul 2>&1
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a IN ('type "%quell_datei%" ^| FINDSTR /n "^"') DO (
    CALL :ers "%%b"
)
GOTO :wer

:ers
set "zeile=%~1"
if defined zeile set "zeile=!zeile:%suchen_nach%=%ersetzen_durch%!"
>>"%ziel_datei%" echo.!zeile!
GOTO :eof

:wer
set installel=%errorlevel%
if %loop%==%count% goto fall
if %installel%==0 goto inta

:fall
echo.
```

Comment: Why not move all the logic in a Powershell script? That would be much more simple to manage than Batch with all of its quirks.

Comment: Well, exclamation marks can be used in batch files, as long as you do not have delayed expansion enabled all the time, but only when actually needed…

Comment: It would be simpler of course, but it should also work this way or not

Comment: @aschipfl When do I need to enable or disable delayed expansion? I tried it before and it didn`t work.

Comment: Delayed expansion is only needed when reading a variable in a parenthesised block of code where it is also set in. Though I have to admit that sub-string replacement is always problematic when search and/or replace expression(s) contain(s) `!`…